# in HTML5 where can I find directory on hard drive, which was created by getDirectory() method?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I am creating, deleting, reading directories but I do not know where to see them on hard drive

```
fs.root.getDirectory('something', {create: true}, function(dirEntry) {
  alert('You have just created the ' + dirEntry.name + ' directory.');
}, errorHandler);
```

Does anyone knows where to see that 'something' folder on hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The JavaScript file system API is sandboxed, for obvious reasons. All you have access to is a unit of isolated storage, you cannot break out of it.

Comment: But I can read file from for example our desktop in windows OS.   right? I have done it and I am interested if I can write something on existing file on hard drive?

Comment: What code did you use to access the Desktop folder? If you used `FileSystemObject` then remember that it isn't a part of the HTML5 filesystem API and is completely separate, and only supported by IE on Windows.